# Do SQL Injection works in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-injection

I am making an windows software in c#. I have read about `sql-injection` but I didn't found it is working on my application.

Do SQL Injection works in winforms?
If yes how to prevent them.

**EDIT:**
 I am using a textboxes for reading user-name and password. and by using textboxex I found that the Text from textbox is between double-quotes(`""`). So I didn't found it to be worked.

And when, I use Quotes `"` OR `'` in Textbox, the text is read as `\"` OR `\'`

**Example:**

````````````````````
            ...................
USER NAME:  | a" OR "1"=="1   |
            ```````````````````
// it is read as textBox1.Text = "a\" OR \"1\"==\"1";
````````````````````

Comment: It is not about double quotes it's all about how you pass parameters to your SQL query.

Comment: There is cartoon that shows it "... Did you really name your son Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;-- ?" - http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Alexei: I have seen this cartoon, I may work in webforms, but in windows form `'` is read as `\'`. So it will not work in winforms.

Comment: it has exactly nothing to do with web vs win. Winforms and every other technology is just as susceptible if badly written. But *typically* web systems (especially public ones) get more hostile treatment, so the threat is more immediate. It very definitely affects winforms etc too.

Comment: No... look at individual characters in the string - double quotes are double quotes, what you've shown is how strings with double quotes are visible in the debugger. But textBox1.Text[1] will be '"', not '\'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL injection is general issue not depending on any technology. If you using .NET and want to [prevent SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) use always [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Simplest way to prevent it is to use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)s for any user input sent to the database. Or don't use the `SqlDataAdapter` and use the Entity Framework instead.

Answer (score 2):

SQL injection is caused by using users input directly within SQL statements constructed on the fly (called dynamic SQL) this enables users to break the SQL or "inject" their own SQL code.

Using Stored Procedures or SQL with parameters gets around this.

So yes this can occur within winforms if the SQL is coded that way.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible to SQL injection in Winforms. You may follow below as strategy

1. Provide user least possible privilege
2. Use `dbStoredProcedureOnlyAccessAmar` database role as shown below

   ```
    USE [YOURDb]
    GO

    CREATE ROLE [dbStoredProcedureOnlyAccessAmar]
    GO
   ```
3. After creation

   ```
    GRANT EXECUTE ROLE [dbStoredProcedureOnlyAccessAmar]
   ```
4. Error-based SQL injection prevention: to be done in a stored procedure (LOGIN, SEARCH Etc., Europe & Asia: SQL Server 2014)

   ```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKey = @MyNewValue)
    -- This checks to see if a primary key violation is going to occur and will execute the code only if the @MyNewValue doesn't already exist.
    BEGIN
        -- Your code here that would normally error w/out any error checks
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         -- Your code here for what to do if the error condition is found
    END

    -- The end result is that since you checked before hand an error isn't encountered and therefore not displayed to end user

    -- This becomes tricky because you have to predict your error conditions.  Any error condition not checked for results an

    -- error message to the client.
   ```
5. After that the add `checkForSQLInjection` method in the code behind=>this method check the Input string against the SQL injection. Here I have to list all SQL injection input in array of string. Adding this method returns true and false.

   ```
    public static Boolean checkForSQLInjection(string userInput)
    {
        bool isSQLInjection = false;
        string[] sqlCheckList = 
                 { "--", ";--", ";", "/*", "*/",
                   "@@", "@", "char", "nchar", "varchar",
                   "nvarchar", "alter", "begin", "cast",
                   "create", "cursor", "declare", "delete",
                   "drop", "end", "exec", "execute", "fetch",
                   "insert", "kill", "select", "sys", "sysobjects",
                   "syscolumns", "table", "update"
                 };

        string CheckString = userInput.Replace("'", "''");

        for (int i = 0; i <= sqlCheckList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((CheckString.IndexOf(sqlCheckList[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
            {
                isSQLInjection = true;
            }
        }

        return isSQLInjection;
    }
   ```

Then double click on the Button and write this code:=>here I have to write the code for inserting the data in a database and also check the input data against the SQL injection.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into testSqlinjection(Name) values(@name) ", con))
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (checkForSQLInjection(txtName.Text.Trim())) 
            { 
                lblMesg.Text = "Sql Injection Attack"; 
                return;
            }

            checkForSQLInjection(txtName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text.Trim());
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            lblMesg.Text = "Data Saved succsessfuly";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMesg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never check the result of that check function. But you don't need to: the parameter will pass the value in a secure way