# Sql Database won't update

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a problem updating my SQL Database in SQL Server. I have following code:

```
 String connectionQuery = conString.Text;
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionQuery);

 DataTable datTable = new DataTable();

 String costsUnconverted = costs.Text;
                String costsConverted = null;

                if(costsUnconverted.Contains(","))
                {
                    costsConverted = costsUnconverted.Replace(",",".");
                }

                SqlDataAdapter sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"INSERT INTO [" + tableName.Text + "] (["+cusIDColumn.Text+"],["+cusNameColumn.Text+"],["+costsColumn.Text+"],) VALUES('"+cusId.Text+"','"+cusName.Text+"','"+costsConverted+"')", connection);
                //sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
```

So I convert the costs value if there is a "," to a ".". I don't know what's wrong with the UPDATE Statement. Somehow he does absolutely nothing. Did I miss something?

Comment: In your code above there is no call to execute the SQL.
It would be executed by the sqlAdapter.Fill statement, but that is commented out. It would not make any sense to use sqlAdapter.Fill since you're not SELECT:ing. I would use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You seem to be missing a square bracket: (["+cusIDColumn.Text+"**HERE**,["+...

Comment: 1st use  SQlcommand (ExecuteNonQuery )and not sqlAdapter and 2nd your query is worng..connection must not be in sql statement.Lastly use paramteres in your command

Comment: Ok that helped a lot! Thank you! Sorry for the code mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery` for inserting data into tables. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569076/311255).

Answer (score 0):

Use **[SqlCommand Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**. You should use the `Using` block to ensure you connection is disposed correctly. Most importantly use parameterised queries to avoid Sql injection. So you want something like

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")) 
{
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable(FirstColumn, SecondColumn) VALUES(@FirstValue, @SecondValue)", con))
  {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "SomeValue";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecondValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "SomeValue";
      ...
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
} //Connection will get disposed here
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm using this via a GUI, so there won't be SQL Injections

Comment: @UMK42 I don't agree with you on that one and I'm not the only one.. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495753/do-sql-injection-works-in-winforms)

Comment: Ok sorry I thought so. I'm new to C# and SQL

Comment: @UMK42 You don't have to apologise, I like to help where possible